# Can't route in Laravel framework

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I create an app with Laravel framework in PHP.

I have a problem with routing.

.htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

routes.php:

```
<?php
get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});


get('1', function() { return 'Je suis la page 1 !'; });
get('2', function() { return 'Je suis la page 2 !'; });
```

When I load http://localhost:63342/game/public/, server loads welcome.blade.php file, so it's okey. But when I want to load http://localhost:63342/game/public/1, I got error: 404 Not Found.
I use appache server and I already enabled 'mod_rewrite' action. 
What can be problem?

Comment: You don't have a route '1' maybe you have to do '/1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
I enabled mod_rewrite action for apache server in httpd.conf, but problem was, that I didn't set correct directory path in this file for my projects.

It should have looked like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs" >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All 
</Directory>
```

Hope, it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that it might be that your laravel app is in a subdirectory. Your rewrite rule should reflect that. I'm not quite sure how your RewriteRule should change but it should be something like this...

```
RewriteRule ^game/public/(.*)/$ /game/public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this is not really an answer... but its something to try.

Hope that helped.